# SSRS 2008: Make detail groupings wrap (horizontal table?)

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

What I have:

```
LONDON          
shoes   7.3 belts   3.1
coats   6.5 glasses 2
trous   4.5 badges  0.5
hats    3.7 socks   -1.2


PARIS           
scarves 7.1 belts   3.1
coats   6.5 glasses 2
pants   4   gloves  0.5
beads   1.2 socks   -1.2


TOKYO           
shoes   8.6 belts   3.1
coats   6.5 glasses 2
trous   4.5 gloves  0.5
hats    3.2 socks   -1.2

ETC…
```

What I want:

```
LONDON                      PARIS                        ETC >>>
shoes   7.3 belts   3.1     scarves 7.1 belts   3.1 
coats   6.5 glasses 2       coats   6.5 glasses 2       <another 2 cities here>
trous   4.5 badges  0.5     pants   4   gloves  0.5 
hats    3.7 socks   -1.2    beads   1.2 socks   -1.2    


DUBLIN                      MOSCOW                       ETC >>>>
scarves 7.1 belts   3.1     scarves 7.1 belts   3.1 
coats   6.5 glasses 2       coats   6.5 glasses 2       <another 2 cities here
pants   4   gloves  0.5     boots   5   gloves  0.5 
beads   1.2 socks   -1.2    beads   4   socks   -1.2    
ETC \/\/\/
```

I think this falls under 'horizontal tables', but not sure

How can I do this in 2008
i.e. get it to 'wrap' the data to the next 'row' of the report when it has written out 4 cities worth of data?
Query is MDX based

The data is currently ranked within a city, so I'm using a rank 'greater than' x to split the data into 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that the cities have a ranking next to them

Then create N tablixes inside one parent/container (N = number of columns you want)

Then you filter the child tablix based on 'Mod N'